# Show app as indicator

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, indicator, ubuntu-dock

I want to see an app as an app indicator (eg. like discord indicator) instead of a full app in the dock. Is there anyway to do so?
There might be an extention but I can't find any.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu by default supports app indicators. However, the app must support that by itself. Apps not supporting that will never appear as an app indicator.